# How do I create an array with undefined length? (In C)

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to create a program which randomly decides how many cards you have, then randomly allocates a value to each of those cards. 
I have managed to randomise the amount of cards, and I know how to randomise their values using an array and a for loop, but the problem is that this method only works when I manually choose a value for the number of elements in the array, but I want the number of elements to be the random amount of cards. 
How do I go about this?
Here's my code so far to show what I mean. And yes, I'm aware the code probably could be done better but this is my first C assignment and I'm a complete beginner.
Thanks :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    system("cls"); /* Clears output to start */

    srand(time(NULL)); /* Sets seed for random number generator */

    int player1_amount = rand() %9 + 2; /*Generates random number for player 1's amount of cards */
    int player2_amount = rand() %9 + 2; /*Generates random number for player 2's amount of cards */

    int a = 1; /* For loop purposes */
    while(a <= 1) /* While loop to print out each player's amount of cards once */
    {
        printf("Player 1 you have %d cards! \n", player1_amount);  
        Sleep(500);
        printf("Player 2 you have %d cards! \n", player2_amount);  
        a++; 
    }    

    Sleep(1000); /* Delays for 1 second before printing card values */

    int values[3]; /* Creates an array with 3 elements, but I want the number of elements to be player1_amount from above */
    int b; /* Random variable for the loop */
    int size = sizeof(values) / sizeof(values[0]); /* Gets length of array */

    for (b = 0; b < size; b++) /* For loop randomises 3 values and then stops */
    {
        values[b] = rand() % 10 +1;
    }

    printf("Player 1 your cards are"); /* For loop to print out the values one after the other */
    for(b = 0; b < size; b++)
    {
        printf(" %d, ", values[b]);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read and learn about *dynamic memory allocation*. Or just use a fixed array with maximum number of cards.

Comment: `int values[player1_amount];` will do the job. It is a variable length array.

Comment: @mch that doesn't work it was the first thing i tried but it returns an error

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks I'll have a look into it. If I use a maximum number of cards (which would be 10), how would I make sure that it only produces player1_amount number of values?

Comment: which error? It is part of the C99 standard.

Comment: I would try to avoid VLAs... But probably it's personal preference.

Comment: This is a screenshot of the error http://prntscr.com/hr26b0

Comment: The solution to your problem is: `int *values = malloc(sizeof(int)*player1_amount);`. Ofcourse malloc might fail, in such case you should check the returned value against NULL, if you don't and it fails, then you will get an undefined bebaviour when you will try to derefrence the returned value.

Comment: Someone already suggested malloc and while I appreciate you providing me with the correct code, I don't know how to use it. Can you give some more info?

Comment: Malloc simply allocates memory dynamically. Really simple. Just read the documentation.

Comment: If you weren't stuck on Windows, you'd have more options available.  Since MSVS is a C90 compiler, you can't use VLA (variable length array) notation, which would be ideal for this.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you've solved it lol :). I'm supposed to submit this on an online compiler my lecturer made, but I preferred VS which is why I was using it. I just tried using the VLA on the online compiler, and it does what I want :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you will want to use [malloc](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~dan/class/165/notes/memory.html)  or [calloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm) for that with a pointer.

```
int *values = (int *)calloc(player1_amount, sizeof(int));
```

Just make sure you free your allocation when done:

```
free(values);
```

Comment: Can you provide some more info on this? I saw mention of malloc while researching but I couldn't figure out how to use it

Comment: @Sam: you need to get your text book out and read up on how to use `malloc()`.  It is medium grade C; not the first thing you learn, but still a part of the basics of C.  There are tutorials aplenty online too, I'm sure.

Comment: The links in there have some example code that you can look at. They are similar to the array declarations. int values[3] = {0,0,0}; works almost the same as int \*values = (int\*) calloc(3, sizeof(int));  In the end, you can still do values[0] = 5; if you like. Its "custom array allocation"...but since its custom, you are responsible for cleaning it up (de-allocating).

Answer (score 0):

C allows you to declare variable sized array. If you are not interested in using functions like malloc or calloc you can simply use variable to declare array as I've done here :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
      int x;

      printf("\nEnter the value of x : ");
      scanf("%d" , &x);

      int array[x];

      for(i = 0 ; i < x ; i++)
      {
              printf("Enter the element : ");
              scanf("%d" , &array[i]);
      }

      for(i = 0 ; i < x ; i++)
      {
             printf("%d  " , array[i]);
      }
}
```

This program runs correctly without any error. So your problem is solved here itself without using malloc or calloc. But just make sure you declare your array after scanning or giving value to your variable which will represent the size of your array(here : x is the variable) and in your case I guess : player1_amount.

But still if you want to use malloc then here it goes :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int x , i;
    int * array;

    printf("\nEnter the value of x : ");
    scanf("%d" , &x);

    array = (int *) malloc(x * sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0 ; i < x ; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the element : ");
        scanf("%d" , &array[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i < x ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d  " , array[i]);
    }
}
```

Both the codes will give you same output.
A little explanation ...

Malloc will take input parameter as the amount of memory you wish to allocate to  given variable(like 'array' in our case) in bytes and will output the pointer to that block of memory.
Since here we are working with integer array the return type is cast as : (int *), had it been a character array we would type cast it as : (char *).